# Is there any chemical to put on windshield to reduce temperature inside a car?

Tags: windshield

As I recall, I read a news 10 years ago about putting some chemical on windshield which can somehow reduce the temperature inside a car.

Since I just bought my car, I want to try. Please help. Thanks

Comment: H2O, when colder than the temperature of the windshield, will reduce the temperature inside the car.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any chemical or coating there may be products which claim to do this but I am unaware of any.

However, you can get clear vehicle tinting which reduce close to 100% of UVA and UVB light this can reduce heating and temperatures in the summer.

This would be a one time application and you wouldn't have to worry about reapplying stuff every-time you wash your vehicle.

[Lumar Auto Solar Control](http://www.llumar.com/en/AutoSolarControl.aspx)

[ForumlaOne UV Shield](http://www.formulaone.com/en/UVShield.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Its been around for ages. Its called window tint. You can either do it yourself or go to a tint shop to have it installed. It takes a few hours to install if you do it yourself. Faster at a tint shop. It'll also require 2 days to cure, which means you can't roll down your window for 2 days.

If you want to do it yourself, the companies Mike Saull linked to are good. Make sure you check with your local state or municipal to see what tint are legal (cops can use illegal tint as a probable cause to pull you over). http://windowtintlaws.org is a good resource.

Once you've done that, just install the thing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBC37rbyYRs is a good guide.

The benefits of having tinted windows are:

- privacy
  cool
- interior
- UV protection
- Shatter protection
- Looks

Hope this helps.